# MongoDB aggregation but not including certain items

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm very new to MongoDB's aggregation framework, so I do not know properly how to do this.

I have a data model that is structured like this:

```
{
  name: String,
  store: {
    item1: Number,
    item2: Number,
    item3: Number,
    item4: Number,
  },
  createdAt: Date
}
```

I want to return the average price of every item'i'. I'm trying with this query:

```
db.commerces.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
        _id: "",
        item1Avg: { $avg: "$store.item1"},
        item2Avg: { $avg: "$store.item2"},
        item3Avg: { $avg: "$store.item3"},
        item4Avg: { $avg: "$store.item4"}
      }
   }
]);
```

The problem is that when an item has no price set, it's stored in the database as a "-1".

I don't want these values to pollute the average result. Is there any way to limit the agreggation to only take into account when price is > 0.

`$match` operator before `$group` is not a solution because I want to return all the average prices.

Thank you!

**EDIT**: Here you have of an example of the input & desired output:

```
[{
  name: 'name',
  store: {
    item1: 10,
    item2: -1,
    item3: 12,
    item4: 3,
  }
},
{
  name: 'name2',
  store: {
    item1: 10,
    item2: -1,
    item3: -1,
    item4: 2,
  }
},...]
```

An the desired output:

```
{
  item1Avg: 10,
  item2Avg: 0,
  item3Avg: 12,
  item4Avg: 2.5
}
```

Comment: Can you show valid documents  with the expected result?

Comment: Make use of the $redact operation.

Comment: Document schema is not enough. please post sample valid JSON documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `store`, then [$match](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) values to meet your condition, then [$group](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) ones that passed the test. Unfortunately there is no way to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) an object, so you need to [$project](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) it to array first:

```
db.commerces.aggregate([
    {$project: {store:[
        {item:{$literal:"item1"}, val:"$store.item1"}, 
        {item:{$literal:"item2"}, val:"$store.item2"}, 
        {item:{$literal:"item3"}, val:"$store.item3"}, 
        {item:{$literal:"item4"}, val:"$store.item4"}
    ]}},
    {$unwind:"$store"},
    {$match: {"store.val":{$gt:0}}},
    {$group: {_id:"$store.item", avg:{$avg:"$store.val"}}}
])
```

**EDIT:**

As  @blakes-seven pointed, it may not work on versions < 3.2. An alternative approach with [$map](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) may work:

```
db.commerces.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        store: {
            $map:{
                input:[
                    {item:{$literal:"item1"}, val:"$store.item1"},
                    {item:{$literal:"item2"}, val:"$store.item2"},
                    {item:{$literal:"item3"}, val:"$store.item3"},
                    {item:{$literal:"item4"}, val:"$store.item4"}
                ],
                as: "i",
                in: "$$i"
            }
        }
    }},
    {$unwind:"$store"},
    {$match: {"store.val":{$gt:0}}},
    {$group: {_id:"$store.item", avg:{$avg:"$store.val"}}}
])
```

Comment: You might note that this would only work in MongoDB 3.2 ( possibly 3.x, not sure of when the change was offhand ) since you cannot just declare the "store" array like that in earlier versions. Using `$map` instead would be more portable to at least 2.6, and there is also another array mapping technique for prior versions to that. Mostly noting as `$map` and `$filter` would actually do this better since it is already tied to MongoDB 3.2.

Comment: Thanks, added an example with map. Don't have any ancient versions handy to test tho.